# Differentiability of an homogeneous and continuous function $f$ ($f(\alpha x)=\alpha^\beta f(x)$)

Tags: functions, derivatives, proof-verification

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\beta$ be a positive real number, and assume that for every real number $x$ and $\alpha$>0

$f(x\alpha)=\alpha^\beta f(x)$

1) if $\beta >1$ show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$

2) if $0<\beta<1$ show that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$

Here's where I am.

let $x=0$

Then $f(0)=\alpha^\beta f(0)$

Hence either $f(0)=0 $ or $\alpha^\beta=1$

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{f(h)}{h}$

Then, I don't know how to continue..
Any Hint?

Comment: I think you meant $f(x)=\alpha ^\beta f(x)$

Comment: I suspect you are dealing with $\beta$-homogenous functions, with $f(\alpha x) = \alpha ^\beta f(x)$

Comment: yep....you are right

Comment: Can you valide useful answers?

Answer (score 1):

As $f$ is continuous, you should have $f(0) = 0$. For any $h$, $\frac{f(h.1)}{h} = \frac{h^\beta f(1)}{h}$ (here, I use the homogeneity on $x=1$ and $\alpha = h$). Thus when $\beta  > 1$, $\frac{f(h)}{h}\to 0$ when $h\to0$. The function is differentiable, with $0$ derivative.

For the second part, one has to assume that $f$ is not identically zero. Then there exists $a \neq0$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$. Then $\frac{f(h)}{h} = h^{\beta-1}\frac{f(a)}{a^\beta}$, which is not bounded around $0$ if $\beta < 1$.

If $f \equiv0 $, it satistifies the [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) property, and is differentiable.

This topic is related to [Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/EulerHomogeneity.pdf).

Comment: Sorry. But since $\alpha$ is a constant here, how do you get $\frac{f(h)}{h} = \frac{h^\beta f(1)}{h}$?

Comment: Only the degree $\beta$ is a constant. I have edited my answer: I used $1$ as $x$, and $h$ as the possibly varying $\alpha$

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was a constant in the first place. That's why I was stuck.

Comment: That was for any real $x$ and (any) $\alpha>0$. Note that continuity is important: an homogeneous function can be discontinuous.