# Differentiability of homogeneous functions in n variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose $f=f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is a homogeneous function

$$f(Cx_1,Cx_2,...,Cx_n)=C^\lambda f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$$

1) Is $f$ differentiable w/respect to all its arguments?

2) Is $f$ differentiable w/respect to all its arguments at the origin?

3) Is $f$ differentiable w/respect to all its arguments at a point, where some of the $x_i$ are negative or zero?

4) Are all partial derivatives of $f$ also differentiable, to what order and where?

Perhaps Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions is related to the question...

When is a homogeneous function also differentiable?

Comment: Euler's Theorem should have the hypothesis that $f$ is differentiable, yes.

Comment: My question is about the reverse direction of Euler's theorem. Suppose $f$ is homogeneous. Can then the 4 questions above be answered with a 'yes'. According to the theorem, this should be the case...

Comment: $f$ need not be defined at the origin or continuous at the origin. I don't follow your point and don't know which direction is which. It is standard to have the differentiability hypothesis, both for the statement and for the proof, since you need it for the chain rule.

Comment: I see...  It turns out, continuity and differentiability are assumed in both directions. One of them is, assume $f$ is homogeneous; the other - assume $f$ has the property $\sum x_i \partial f/ \partial x_i  = \lambda f $

But differentiability cannot be inferred from $f$ being homogeneous and having the listed ("sum") property, correct?

Comment: They have tried to prove it for the case of  a single-variable function
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555847/differentiability-of-an-homogeneous-and-continuous-function-f-f-alpha-x-a

Comment: The issue is *not* differentiability at the origin; as I've already pointed out, the function may not even be defined at the origin. I do not know an example offhand of a (continuous) function that has partial derivatives everywhere (except the origin) but is *not* differentiable and yet satisfies that equation. Is there a function that has directional derivative $Df_{\vec x}(\vec x)$ in direction $\vec x$ at $\vec x$ for every $x\ne 0$ without being differentiable?

Comment: Can you give me a “closed form function” that is not continuously differentiable?

Comment: I guess I have to accept the answer below. It points out well that continuity is one condition that I missed; and that homogeneity does not imply differentiability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not always. Take for example the function

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} x & y=0 \\ y & x=0 \\ 0 & \text{else} \\ \end{cases}$$

It is homogenous, but not even continuous, let alone differentiable. The partials in all directions do exist, however, at the origin and everywhere else off-axis. This doesn't make it differentiable at the origin, though.

Comment: thank you for this answer, what if we add the requirement for $f$ to be a closed-form function

Comment: @user142523 I would argue that would be a nonsensical condition. Anything can be considered "closed-form" or an "elementary" function if you want to write down a definition. For example do we include Elliptic functions? Bessel functions? That condition imo is a cultural one, not a mathematical one. Ted Shifrin suggested a sensible alternative in his comment.

Comment: It seems I should have added the requirement for $f$ to be continuous ... this is what they did for the single-variable case
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555847/differentiability-of-an-homogeneous-and-continuous-function-f-f-alpha-x-a